# My node js deployed app defaults to 3000 despite using process.env.PORT

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, port

I am trying to deploy my Node app. In app.listen I am using process.env.PORT but my service provide keeps telling me that my app is only running on port 3000.

I have searched for hours in vain and cannot figure out what I gave done wrong.
my APP.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var connection = require('./routes/connection');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var clientRoutes        = require('./routes/clients'),
dashboardRoutes      = require('./routes/dashboard'),
carerRoutes         = require('./routes/carers'),
indexRoutes         = require('./routes/index'),
shiftRoutes         = require('./routes/shifts'),
timesheetRoutes     = require('./routes/timesheets'),
reportRoutes        = require('./routes/reports'),
graphRoutes         = require('./routes/graph'),
adminRoutes         = require('./routes/admin'),
registerRoutes      = require('./routes/register');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressValidator());//immedietely after body parser
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var options = {
    host: DATABASE_LOCATION,
    user: DATABASE_USER,
    database: DATABASE_NAME,
    password: DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    multipleStatements: true //for more than one query in a get route
};

var sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

app.use(session({
  secret: '12fgsgsdfadfafafasfss',
  resave: false,
  store: sessionStore,
  saveUninitialized: false
  // cookie: { secure: true }
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {
    // console.log(username);
    // console.log(password);


 connection.query('select id, password from users where username = ?', [username], function(err, results, fields){
      if (err) { done(err)};
      if (results.length === 0) {
        done(null, false);
      } else {
        const hash = results[0].password.toString();
        var user_id = results[0].id;

        bcrypt.compare(password, hash , function(err, response){
          if (response) {
            return done(null, {user_id: user_id});
          } else {
            return done(null, false);
          };
        });
      };
    }); 
  }));

app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use(dashboardRoutes);
app.use(carerRoutes);
app.use(clientRoutes);
app.use(shiftRoutes);
app.use(timesheetRoutes);
app.use(reportRoutes);
app.use(graphRoutes);
app.use(adminRoutes);
app.use(registerRoutes);



app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
   console.log(`Wayne's server started.....`);
});
```

My connection.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: DATABASE_LOCATION,
  user: DATABASE_USER,
  database: DATABASE_NAME,
  password: DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  multipleStatements: true //for more than one query in a get route
});

module.exports = connection;
```

I tried deploying to a different host and lo and behold when I look at the logs it states it is running on port 3000 and wont open the home page. I am aware it wont connect to the databasejust yet, I just want the app to get running first.

I really cannot fathom what I have done wrong. But I suspect I did something wrong when creating environment variables in my console.

Comment: How are you deploying? And how are you providing env vars?

Comment: On fastComet I deployed via FTP and dis providse environment variables but not for PORt, just stuck to proces.env.PORT. The exact same on evennode except deployed via git.

Answer (score 1):

On our servers there are actually 2 ways of deploying NodeJS application.

---

**The first one** is indeed using our NodeJS selector as @Alpe89 suggested.

The selector service is intended for customers running multiple NodeJS application on different NodeJS versions. The selector works in conjunction with the Apache Mod Passenger and it creates a virtual environment for every application that is deployed.

This means that for each application you can have different environment variables or even the same environment variables but with different values set for those.

To actually configure an environment variable for an application created with the NodeJS selector, you should use the included in the selector functionality called the same way:

https://www.screencast.com/t/uh4dVAo1VM2J

---

**The second one** is to use directly the fixed NodeJS version that is running by default on the server.

This will allow you to directly set environment variables using SSH with the following command:

```
export SOME_ENV_VAR="Some value"
```

Also you can set the environment variables in the env object directly using the following code in your Javascript files:

```
process.env.PORT= 3001;
```

However, running an application with the default NodeJS service means that you should start the application from within SSH. This we have described in details right here:

https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/nodejs/pm2

---

As a conclusion, no matter which approach you will use, defining a port is actually both correct and incorrect. The reason is purely because of the way how the shared hosting for NodeJS works. Hosting multiple client applications on the same server means that every application should be running on different port. The NodeJS selector feature actually provides the PORT variable if not defined and it does it in a way that it is impossible for 2 clients' applications to run on the same port. Therefore if you choose to set the port manually you might potentially struggle to find a free port depending of course on the server your account is hosted at.

Answer (score 0):

I must have done something wrong. I created a new folder for the app. I then copied all the files and then did a new git init and npm init. I then did npm install and deployed and it all works fine. Why, I cannot say but it worked.